# c# JSON array, running foreach on a nested dictionary

Tags: c#, json.net

Sorry for the very ambiguous title but I don't quite know the question I am asking and have spent a couple of hours reading questions on here and am none the wiser!

I have a json array which looks like this:

```
{
  "terms": "http://www.xe.com/legal/dfs.php",
  "privacy": "http://www.xe.com/privacy.php",
  "from": "USD",
  "amount": 1,
  "timestamp": "2018-08-14T00:00:00Z",
  "to": [
    {
      "quotecurrency": "EUR",
      "mid": 0.8771637444
    },
    {
      "quotecurrency": "GBP",
      "mid": 0.7835914281
    }
  ]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
public class DeserializeEX
{
    //public string Disclaimer { get; set; }
    //public string License { get; set; }
    public string Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public DeserializeEXto To;
}

public class DeserializeEXto
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> To { get; set; }
}
```

The bit I can't work out now is how to access that dictionary when deserializing?

This obviously doesn't work because `result4.To` isn't the correct thing to look at:

```
var result4 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeserializeEX>(response);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry4 in result4.To)
{
    outputData.Rows.Add(result4.Timestamp, loadBaseCurr, entry4.Key, entry4.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DeserializeEXto` class is wrong, it should really look like this:

```
public class DeserializeEXto
{
    public string QuoteCurrency { get; set; }
    public double Mid { get; set; }
}
```

And the `To` property in the root class needs to be this:

```
public IEnumerable<DeserializeEXto> To { get; set; }
```

And now your loop will look something like this:

```
foreach (var entry4 in result4.To)
{
    outputData.Rows.Add(result4.Timestamp, loadBaseCurr, entry4.QuoteCurrency, entry4.Mid);
}
```

Comment: A worthy mention I think... (because I released his property is wrong after I posted my answer); if you copy the JSON structure, then in VS go to `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes` it'll generate the right class structure for you.

Comment: @adriani6 that is excellent thank you, I don't have that feature installed so didn't even know it existed, that would have saved some time!

Comment: @AdamDavies It's part of VS, it's not an addon feature.

Comment: @davidG yes I need to tweak the install though as I obviously don't have that component installed :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your model matches your json. Main issue is that for your `to`, it's actually an object array, instead of a dictionary.
Try this model:

```
public class CurrencyDTO
{
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string Privacy { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
    public List<QuoteCurrencyDTO> To { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteCurrencyDTO
{
    public string QuoteCurrency { get; set; }
    public double Mid { get; set; }
}
```